# Webservice returning void result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a C# webservice that connects to SQL database and grabs data by executing a stored procedure:

```
 public class myproj : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string projmethod(string pnumber)
        {
            List<Projectdetails> projectdetails = new List<Projectdetails>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstring"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myprocedure",con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@projectid", pnumber);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Projectdetails proj = new Projectdetails();
                    proj.projectid = rdr["projectid"].ToString();
                    proj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    proj.contextname = rdr["contextname"].ToString();
                    projectdetails.Add(proj);
                }
            }
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            var result = serializer.Serialize(projectdetails);
            Context.Response.Write(result);
         return result.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This is the .acmx.cs file code. I am trying to link this webservice to a webform - button click method:

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False">Enter Project numbers</asp:Label> 
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="46px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 
Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>   
            </div>
        </form>
```

In my aspx.cs file I have the below code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                localhost.myproj det = new localhost.myproj();
                var textinput = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
                string result = det.projmethod(textinput);
                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label2.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label2.Text ="something wrong!";
            }
        }
    }
```

When compiling my web service I am seeing This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error..

Not seeing any further details in the webservice.

Any help on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Your webservice method _is_ void: `public void projmethod(string pnumber)`. Why do you think, it is not?

Comment: `string result = det.projmethod(textinput);` yet you define `projmethod` with the signature as `void projmethod(string)`

Comment: On a side note do not use empty `catch` blocks that do not rethrow the exception. You are losing everything about what went wrong in your application. Either log the exception in its entirety or rethrow it using `throw;`

Comment: Sorry I am editing my question. Yes my webservice is using void but I want to change it to string and add a return statement. I did so and I am editing the question with my code changes

Comment: I have changed the method signature. But on the output of the webform I am seeing just [] and not the JSON output of the webservice

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the web service and switched it to dataset return type:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataSet (string pnumber)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconstr"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcomm.Connection = sqlConn;
            using (sqlConn)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        // This will be your input parameter and its value
                        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid", pnumber);                    
                        sqlcomm.CommandText = "mystoredprocedure";
                        da.SelectCommand = sqlcomm;
                        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return new DataSet();


        }
    }
```

And it worked!! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just change de signature of method to string instead `void`. Then, return `result`. Something like this:

`[WebMethod]
    public string projmethod(string pnumber)
    {
        List<Projectdetails> projectdetails = new List<Projectdetails>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myprocedure",con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@projectid", pnumber);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Projectdetails proj = new Projectdetails();
                proj.projectid = rdr["projectid"].ToString();
                proj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                proj.contextname = rdr["contextname"].ToString();
                projectdetails.Add(proj);
            }
        }
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        var result = serializer.Serialize(projectdetails);
        return result;
    }`

Comment: This is what I have in my question. When doing this I am seeing [] in my webform output.